Write Access Violation when Serializing rapidjson::GenericDocument with PrettyWriter to GenericStringBuffer
I am working with RapidJSON and trying to serialize a rapidjson::GenericDocument object using rapidjson::PrettyWriter to a rapidjson::GenericStringBuffer. Here is the relevant part of my code:
typedef rapidjson::GenericDocument<rapidjson::UTF16<> > WDocument;
typedef rapidjson::GenericStringBuffer<rapidjson::UTF16<> > WStringBuffer;

WStringBuffer buffer;
PrettyWriter<WStringBuffer, WDocument::EncodingType> writer(buffer);
doc.Accept(writer);

While writing to the buffer(using Accept method), I am encountering a "Write Access Violation" exception. Upon debugging, I observed that the violation is caused because the stack_ (which RapidJSON uses to store the strings) of the string buffer is null.


From my understanding, this stack_ should dynamically expand depending on the data being written to the buffer. The only reason for this stack_ to be null should be a memory allocation failure.
However, the process running this code is a 32-bit process, and the maximum memory it consumed, as observed in Task Manager, is about 800 MB (which is less than the memory available for the process).
I found an issue on GitHub (835), related to stack_. This seems to be similar to the problem I am facing.
I am unable to figure out the reason for this failure and have been stuck on this for a long time. Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

However, the process running this code is a 32-bit process, and the maximum memory it consumed, as observed in Task Manager, is about 800 MB (which is less than the memory available for the process). This actually could be the problem on MS Windows. If this stack_ is several hundred MB you may not have enough unfragmented address space to allocate a second larger contiguous memory region to copy the old stack_ to the new.

Side note: It's hard to get a null pointer out of C++ allocation routines. Typically if they can't give you an object, they throw an exception. The notable exception to this is malloc and its family.

@user4581301 Thanks for the hint. You are right, the rapidjson allocator is returning null while resizing the stack. This null pointer is not from C++ allocation routines. I will debug the rapidjson allocator to know in what case they are returning null pointer.
